# store user ID in Session or encrypted cookie for a long time?

Tags: security

in web application like a society networks users log in and do some works for long times like 2 hours or more, now i store some data like user ID (identity number in member table) in session and found users details data by this id .

and when each user log in to site i store this data for that user on session for 2 hours.
for this work i set my session time out on 120minutes and i want to know is this work good?
i mean storing session for 2hours.

in another hand i can store that ID on encrypted cookie on client and i want to know is this way secure and if user/hacker can decrypt my cookie and retrieve user id (this id is my identity table id) can attack to my site and do some thing or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the world of Web, information storage connections in the session variable is wrong path. You do not control the session variable and can be lost at all momments.

I do not know the architecture used, but on an IIS server you can configure the encryption key for the authentication cookie in your Web.config file on your site web

```
<machineKey validationKey = "AutoGenerate, IsolateApps"
             decryptionKey = "AutoGenerate, IsolateApps"
             validation = "SHA1" decryption = "Auto" />
```

It is not possible that this information is hack on client side.

This is the better way

Comment: you mean if user retrieve that info can not do something?

Comment: Yes exactly. Only the web site can decrypt user data in authentification cookie.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with storing identification with a cookie is probably not decrypting the cookie but steeling the cookie as whole. This is common session and permanent cookies.

If you want to not to bother user with new login while the site is still active in browser consider shorter session timeout combined with a javascript keep alive (e.g. page refresh each 10min). Otherwise you have on server lot of sessions no longer needed.

If you want to keep user loged in even if browser window is closed. Consider including a browser identification information in the cookie (e. g. [Is browser fingerprinting a viable technique for identifying anonymous users?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122372/is-browser-fingerprinting-a-viable-technique-for-identifying-anonymous-users)) with good server encryption.

Don't forget to force https.

Answer (score 0):

Do not store in an encrypted cookie. Store in a **signed** cookie. It's different, here is the why:

https://spring.io/blog/2014/01/20/exploiting-encrypted-cookies-for-fun-and-profit#modifying-the-decrypted-value

The 'old' alternative of having a session, is a bit less scalable than relying on a signed cookie, but it should be more secure, even if someone like NSA has all kinds of ways to go around signing/encryption. ** ˆˆparanoid statement ˆˆ ** but then again, if they have that, they will most likely also have man in the middle access and all sorts of sessions would be pointless.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I offer the same solution as the link does in the first sentence, the link it's just the why, and it's not easy to sum it up, because if people want proof, that blog post that probably exceeds 30k characters and is the best most summed up way to do it.

Comment: @skrilled: did you flag my answer? you said that "While this link may answer the question" -> it does not answer the question, it explains the why. if you did and somehow can unflag it, please do